# ScrollPane sliders/bar width?

Tags: libgdx

I need help cant figure this by myself how to change ScrollPane width in libgdx ? because now its the size as I upload it and I need it to be on all sizes the same width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put *container* inside `ScrollPane` (`Table` for example) and setup required size:

```
Table contentRoot = new Table();
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(contentRoot);
scrollPane.setSize(width, height);
```

You need to add uploaded content to *container* (`contentRoot`). In this case `ScrollPane` will save size and scroll bars will be automatically enabled:

```
contentRoot.add(uploadedContent).row();
```